# copy the x files from a folder to another

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I've a folder full of files around 7000 and I need to copy or move after the first x files to another folder.

my current simple script is:

```
for file in $(ls -p | grep -v / | tail -100)
  do
  echo $file
  cp $file "/other /Folder"

done
```

but it's not working when there is space in the file name. Command grep only takes the first part of the name. I'm open to any suggestion and learn how to do?

Comment: You need to quote $file, e.g. "$file"

Comment: I agree with @user3439894. Whitespace or any special characters will not work with your script. As a general rule, do not parse the output of ls. Parameter and command substitutions should be double-quoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a simple `for` loop and a `count` to skip the first `count` number of files and move the rest, e.g. skipping the first `3` files (or folders):

```
$ skip=3; for i in *; do ((skip > 0)) && { ((skip--)); continue; }; mv "$i" "$destdir"; done
```

or, in script form:

```
skip=3
for i in *; do 
    ((skip > 0)) && { ((skip--)); continue; }
    mv "$i" "$destdir"
done
```

Comment: Hmm. that is strange, what OS/shell are you running? It shouldn't matter as POSIX arithmetic handling and comparison are used. You can try `[ "$skip" -gt '0' ] && { skip=$( expr "$skip" - 1 ); continue; }` if your platform is having difficulty with the POSIX `((...))` notation. (make sure there *are* spaces in `expr "$skip" - 1` if you go that route) You can also try *hinting* to the shell that `skip` is an `integer` with `declare -i skip` to begin with, or try `skip=$((skip-1))` instead of `((skip--))`

Comment: It works fine in OS X El Capitan 10.11.5:  `BASH_VERSION='3.2.57(1)-release'`

Comment: I'm on sierra beta 5 ... I had it working by putting the mv command before the  ((skip > 0)) && { ((skip--)); continue; }